# excel formating - losing 0 values

Tags: excel

I have a big CSV file and I want to edit some things and save it, but there is one column that has values like this:

```
0892076002251
```

After I did change and save that value in these columns lose the 0 in the beginning so, in the end, I receive:

```
892076002251
```

What I need to do so the zeros stay after I change some stuff in my CSV file?

If I format everything like text my value will be like this:

```
892076000000
```

SO I think it needs to be a number

Comment: Format the column as text prior to importing.

Comment: @ScottCraner I updated my description. I already tried that option, but it doesn't work

Comment: It would really help your question to list the exact steps you took to "edit some things and save it" and also how you're looking at the file after saving it.  Whenever you open it in excel, excel is going to try to be "helpful" and end up making changes.  If you want to know exactly what's in your CSV file without invoking excel's "assistance", open it in a text editor (notepad/wordpad etc)

Comment: During the import process into Excel, you need to declare that column as Text. Exactly how to do that depends on exactly how you are accomplishing the import. I suspect your lack of results from formatting *everything like text* is because you're not correctly accomplishing the import. But you need to provide the specifics of exactly what you are doing.